# Computer boots after turning on power supply

Tags: boot, motherboard

I have a Mainboard N68-S3 UCC.

When I turn on power supply, then the PC boots. I have inserted a new BIOS battery, resetet BIOS, and double checked if the `POWER SW` is connected correctly as in the [docs](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/N68-S3%20UCC.pdf):

[image]

I have connected the  `POWER SW` with the two dots called "PWRBTN". However the problem remains.

I noticed, that when I turn off the power supply for only a short moment, like 20 seconds, and then turn on the power supply, the PC wont boot automatically. However, if its turned off for some minutes, it boots again.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Many BIOS settings have an option to boot the system after "power returns" - this is often used to boot unattended PCs after a power outage. Very likely you have set this.